# Can Singleton Gui Framework cause a Stack-Overflow? If not, is all loaded data lost between GUI frames?

Tags: java, user-interface, singleton, stack-overflow

I've been working on an app that's similar to a dnd character sheet, and I hate working with GUI's. I thought of using something not unlike a MVC pattern for handling the GUI framework (how panels are loaded or hidden), but in my approach I ended up combining it with a Singleton pattern to establish a base class called GUI_Controller that all panels were then loaded onto via method calls. This let me create each new "page" or "sheet" as a separate class, and when I needed it to be "loaded" all I had to do was use the method call within the Singleton GUI_Controller. This approach seems to work, and I like how it makes the framework of the GUI easy to follow. My question is, is this OK? or is this only working for now? I didn't know if the way the control works, if this could lead to a stack overflow error if the "view" kept shifting enough with more and more method calls to classes stacking up. Or if by returning to the Singleton each time, the stack was being kept clean, but resulting in any data "loaded" by one class's call being "erased" and then "re-loaded" when that class's call was called again (ex: clicking on the spells page, going back to character page, then clicking on spells page again).

If so, the data is called via a "Database" class that connects an SQL database. Would it then be best to front load the database before initially moving scope to the Singleton?

The Singleton for GUI_Controller looks like this..

```
public class GUI_Controller extends JFrame{
   private static GUI_Controller singleton = new GUI_Controller();

private GUI_Controller() {
    initialize();
}

public static GUI_Controller getSingleton() {
    if(singleton == null) {
        singleton = new GUI_Controller();
    }
    return singleton;
}

private JFrame frame;


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLocation(100,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
    
}


public void setHomePage() {
    HomePage hp = new HomePage();
    
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(hp);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public void setSpellsPage() {
    SpellsPage sp = new SpellsPage();
    
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and other classes access the Singleton in ways like

```
GUI_Controller gui = GUI_Controller.getSingleton();
    gui.setHomePage();
```

and

```
btnViewSpells.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            GUI_Controller gui = GUI_Controller.getSingleton();
            gui.setSpellsPage();
        }
    });
```

I'll add a note that each class is not a single JPanel, but acts as a "frame" having it's own design and card layout views. I came up with this overall framework to simplify the GUI control, but now I don't know if it's just over-programming.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're describing, essentially, a "god class", where all the responsibility is passed through this one class.  To my mind, that's going to end up in a mess of branching logic and state (mis)management. Why I would certainly agree with having a single window as the base component, I would be focused on decoupling the navigation workflows, data and state management from the UI and individual views. I'd make use of things like dependency injection to pass data, observer patterns to make the interactions between the view(s) and the models

Comment: Navigation is actually a complex problem and can end up in spaghetti very fast, especially if you have a non-linear workflow.  In the past I've build navigation workflows which are independent of each other, but which allows one navigation controller to pass control off to another (so one nav controller becomes a child of another). This allows the each navigation controller to be specialised for it's particular needs without the need to expose functionality or workflows to parties which don't need it

Comment: I've also coupled the navigation controllers with a navigation "model" and "view factory" concept, so that the controller itself becomes a re-usable, self contained unit of work, which "delegates" parts of it's functionality to the model and factory, so you don't have to have all the views initialised at the same time and can control the flow of navigation based on the available state (been passed between the views and the model)

Comment: So, I guess my "basic" answer is, no, it's not a good idea.  You should aim to "decouple" as much of the workflow as you can and not rely on hard coded paths if possible - use models/delegation instead - IMHO.  You could also make use of different UI containers, like `JTabbedPane` to allow the user to more freely choose which views that want to look at

Comment: MVC is also a multi layered capable.  That is, a MVC can contain one or more MVC 

Comment: So, maybe then instead of a "god class", use a constructor (or some method) to pass the "base frame component" to the class that's "in view"? That way they share the same core characteristics, but the "flow" would be less dependent on a singular class, and more dynamic in how it can internally navigate between classes?  Now that I'm typing this, it kinda sounds like the base frame could behave more like an interface that the other classes then "build off of"

Comment: So, if you're really willing to take some time and effort, you could have a look at [this "conceptual" idea for a Swing based navigation controller](https://github.com/RustyKnight/SimpleSwingNavigationController) and if you're still keen, you could have a look [at this, crazier idea](https://github.com/RustyKnight/SwingNavigationControllerPane)

Comment: Your advice has been greatly appreciated!  After your initial comments about dependency injection, I've started looking into using the Spring frame-work, and how that could help. And now with those additional resources given, I'm going to try and digest as much as I can from their design layout to see what sort of "mixed integration" I could implement from combining the different design concepts.